# How to implement framerate-independent acceleration depending on current velocity

Tags: physics, movement, frame-rate

For my client/server application, I've implemented framerate-independent acceleration like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960251/6077426).

Now I've advanced my formula to be using the current velocity of the moving object to calculate the acceleration factor. This causes a problem: if the client and server have different tick rates (e.g. 120 and 30 fps respectively) the movement calculated on the client is not equal to the movement calculated on the server anymore.

I've tried to update the acceleration factor on the faster ticking peer with the framerate of the slower ticking peer (i.e. the server). I can see slight improvements here, but it's far from good. I've also tried on the slower ticking machine to calculate the root mean square of the velocity of the last frame and the current velocity and calculate the acceleration factor with it. Again, does not really fix the problem.

Could anyone provide me with a clever solution or workaround if there is one?

Comment: Why do the server and the client have different tick rates?

Comment: because the server has more to do than the client, it should only refresh at 30fps

Comment: The answer you've linked to is entirely incorrect.  [I've added a new answer to that post explaining the error and offering some alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65280633/3064164), but they won't be sufficient to solve your problem, which is more fundamental than just numeric cleverness.